# Store JSON loaded data for use in a Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I've been sruggling to store data loaded from a Json using AngularJS in a variable I want to use on another controller to load another json.'

HTML

```
<ul bn-delegate="li a | selectNodes(x)">
    <li ng-repeat="x in nodes">
        <!-- Delegate target. -->
        <a href="#">{{x.name}}</a>
        <!-- Delegate target. -->
    </li>
</ul>
<div ng-show="selectedNodes">
    <p>
        You selected: {{selectedNodes.id}} : {{selectedNodes.name}}
        <script>
        </script>
    </p>
    <div ng-app="nodesApp" ng-controller="compsCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="x in nodes">
            {{x.id}}+ {{x.name}}
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('nodesApp', []);
    app.controller('nodesCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.selectNodes = function (nodes) {
            $scope.selectedNodes = nodes;

        };
        $http.get("environments.json")
            .success(function (response) {
                console.log(response.nodes);
                $scope.nodes = response.nodes;
                $scope.selectedNodes = null;
            });
    });

    app.controller('compsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
        console.log($scope);
        init();

        function init() {
            $http.get('comps-' + evid + '.json')
                .success(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.nodes);
                    $scope.nodes = response.nodes;
                });
        }
    });

    app.directive(
        "bnDelegate",
        function ($parse) {
            function link($scope, element, attributes) {
                var config = attributes.bnDelegate.split("|");
                if (config.length === 1) {
                    var selector = "a";
                    var expression = config[0];
                }
                else {
                    var selector = config[0];
                    var expression = config[1];
                }
                var expressionHandler = $parse(expression);
                element.on(
                    "click.bnDelegate",
                    selector,
                    function (event) {

                        event.preventDefault();

                        var localScope = $(event.target).scope();

                        localScope.$apply(
                            function () {
                                expressionHandler(localScope);
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
                $scope.$on(
                    "$destroy",
                    function (event) {
                        element.off("click.bnDelegate");
                    }
                );
            }
            return ({
                link: link,
                restrict: "A"
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

What i want to do is take the {{selectedNodes.id}} data and store it in a variable for use in the compsCtrl, excactly in the $http.get, in the evid variable.

The directive is used for showing the info in the ng-show in the html part, but I seem to not be able to use that for my  purposes.

Comment: Create a service or factory that houses the $http call (not a good practice to store these $http calls in controllers anyways... try to keep controller skinny).  Once you have a service created and linked to each of your controllers, you can resolve the JSON value in the service and then assign it to a scope obj.

Comment: Mind illustrating me please? I have zero to little idea how to do it :(

Comment: can you provide your code here?